# (CSS&LESS) Multiple select element, style selected option

Tags: css, select, styles, less

I'm trying to style the selected item in a multiple select element using CSS & LESS.
Couldn't really find something about this, especially not in combination with LESS.

This is my HTML:

```
<label for="userGroups">Select usergroup</label>
<select name="userGroups[]" multiple="multiple" id="userGroups">
    <option value="1">Root</option>
    <option value="2">WebMaster</option>
</select>
```

And this is my CSS/LESS:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;

    &[multiple] {
        option:selected {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

I also wrote the following code, wich **is** working:

```
&:not([multiple]) {
    background: url("../images/arrow.png") no-repeat 95% 50%;
}
```

Hope someone knows the answer for this, thanks instead :)

Comment: Did you try `option:checked` instead of `selected`?  Also, I think I remember something about `color` not being able to be set, but background can be...  but I could be wrong, I would research that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it should be `:checked` instead of `:selected` but the main problem is that most of browsers simply ignore any custom properties for `option:pseudo`. A common workaround is to use some javascript library that emulates select via ul/li.

Comment: For instance: setting color via `option:hover` works in FF and old Opera, but does not in Chrome (and its Webkit family). And `option:checked` works in none.